# BASH: Filling template file with strings

Tags: bash

I have a template script with some analysis and the only thing that I need to change in it is a `case`.

```
#!/bin/bash
CASE=XXX
... the rest of the script where I use $CASE
```

I created a list of all my `cases`, that I saved into file: `list.txt`.
So my list.txt file may contain cases as XXX, YYY, ZZZ.

Now I would run a loop over `list.txt` content and fill my `template_script.sh` with a `case` from the `list.txt` and then saved the file with a new name - `script_CASE.sh`

```
for case in `cat ./list.txt`; 
do
# open template_script.sh
# use somehow the line from template_script.sh (maybe substitute CASE=$case)
# save template_script with a new name script_$case
done
```

Comment: Use: `while read -r c; do sed "s/^CASE=.*/CASE=$c/" template_script.sh > "script_{c).sh"; done < list.txt`

Comment: You know that you can export variables with `export CASE=xxx` and that this variables are available in your script? Rewriting code is in most cases a silly idea. If you really need templates, you should consider an appropriate tool like [`m4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)).

Comment: @anubhava thanks for nice piece of code - there is one small mistake, but this works perfectly for me: `while read -r c; do sed "s/^CASE=.*/CASE=$c/" template_script.sh > "script_${c}.sh"; done < list.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this `bash` script:

```
while read -r c; do
    sed "s/^CASE=.*/CASE=$c/" template_script.sh > "script_${c}.sh"
done < list.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

In pure *bash* :

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r casevalue; do
    escaped=${casevalue//\'/\'\\\'\'} # escape single quotes if any
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line = CASE=* ]]; then
            echo "CASE='$escaped'"
        else
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done < template_script.sh > "script_$casevalue"
done < list.txt
```

Note that saving to "script_$casevalue" may not work if the case contains a `/` character.

If it is guaranteed that case values (lines in list.txt) needn't to be escaped then using `sed` is simpler:

```
while IFS= read -r casevalue; do
    sed -E "s/^CASE=(.*)/CASE=$casevalue/" template_script.sh > "script_$casevalue"
done < list.txt
```

But this approach is fragile and will fail, for instance, if a case value contains a `&` character. The pure `bash` version, I believe, is very robust.